# Host Header Injection in test lab

Tags: security, host-headers

Trying to see if a server (in test lab) is vulnerable to host header injection or not. In second scenario where I insert host header as "www.cow.com", still get 302 Found. Does this mean this is vulnerable to host injection ? If it were not, would I see 404 not found?

Scenario 1:

```
kali01:~$ curl -v http://10.10.10.10/login.html

* Trying 10.10.10.10:80...

* TCP_NODELAY set

* Connected to 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10) port 80 (#0)

> GET /login.html HTTP/1.1

> Host: 10.10.10.10

> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0

> Accept: */*

>

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found

< Location: https://10.10.10.10:443/login.html

< Connection: close

< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000, preload

< X-Frame-Options: DENY

< Content-Length: 0
```

2. Scenario 2:

When host header [www.cow.com](http://www.cow.com) is inserted, I still get 302 Found.

```
kali01:~$ curl -H "Host:www.cow.com" -v http://10.10.10.10/login.html

* Trying 10.10.10.10:80...

* TCP_NODELAY set

* Connected to 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10) port 80 (#0)

> GET /login.html HTTP/1.1

> Host:www.cow.com

> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0

> Accept: */*

>

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

< HTTP/1.1 302 Found

< Location: https://www.cow.com:443/login.html

< Connection: close

< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000, preload

< X-Frame-Options: DENY

< Content-Length: 0

<

* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: It redirected to the web app, didn't it?

Comment: Yes, from curl output it says so. But when I paste that https://www.cow.com:443/login.html, I cant open a web on a browser. I am sure I am missing something or curl output of getting redirection is enough for a web to prove vulnerable?

Comment: Yes, the curl output is enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: What happens if you have `curl` connect over https instead of plain http?

Comment: with https, I still see 200 ok.                                                                               
kali01:~$ curl -H "Host:www.crm.com" -v https://10.10.10.10/login.html -k
<......>
> GET /login.html HTTP/1.1
> Host:www.crm.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Sep 2021 15:38:23 GMT
< Etag: "614c9f6f.636"
< Expires: 0
< Cache-Control: max-age=15552000, must-revalidate